# Example of a linear transformation where kernel = image

Tags: linear-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Let $T$ be the linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. Find an example of such $T$ where $\ker T = \text{im } T$.

Comment: My bad about the incorrect example. Rank-Nullity tells you $\dim(\ker T)+\dim(\text{Im } T)=2 \implies \dim(\ker T)=\dim(\text{Im } T)=1$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linear Transformation with kernel equal to image](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230927/linear-transformation-with-kernel-equal-to-image)

Comment: In addition, I believe all such examples are projections (and this also generalizes to higher even dimensions) if you consider the problem geometrically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the linear map defined by $T(1,0) := (0,0)$ and $T(0,1) = (1,0)$. In matrix form,

$$ \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$