# When do we have ker $T$ = im $S$ and im $T$ = ker $S$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I was thinking about kernel and image and wondered: If $T$ and $S$ are linear transformations from $V$ to $V$, when do we have ker $T$ = im $S$ and im $T$ = ker $S$? Is there any significance to this? Or is it just something trivial? I know [it is possible when $T = S$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2376702/example-of-a-linear-transformation-where-kernel-image?noredirect=1&lq=1), but how about when $T \neq S$?

I was drawing pictures and it seems that if this is possible, then $T$ and $S$ would sort of be “dual” to each other, which I’ve tried to illustrate in my drawing below. (I’m using “dual” in a general, colloquial sense, not in the sense of dual map.) They map into each other’s kernels. Another simple observation is that $T \circ S = S \circ T = 0$.

[image]

Edit: an answer below has mentioned that if $P$ is any projection, then $T = P$ and $S = I - P$ work. Some more questions I have are:

- Are these the only possibilities?
- Observe that in this case (if we have an inner product) each map's image is orthogonal to its kernel, and we can write $V$ as a direct sum of these two subspaces. Is this a necessary condition in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example where this happens is when $T=P$ and $S=I-P$ where $P$ is any projection.

Comment: @ Kavi: in your example, $P$ has only to be a projection, $P^2=P.$ An inner product on $V$ is not given.

Comment: @Fred Thanks for the comment. I was just trying to give one non-trivial example where the conditions are satisfied. I have now removed the word 'orthogonal' from my answer.

Comment: Ok, nice. Do you know if that characterizes all of them? Also, is the map $I - P$ important, like does it show up anywhere? I was wondering how you might have thought of it.

Comment: For an orthogonal projection, I can picture $(I - P)v$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (for example) as the vector perpendicular to $Pv$ that is needed to go from $Pv$ to $v$.